# Starting Jetty returns: ERROR : Nothing to start, exiting

Tags: jetty

I want to serve a directory so I could open an html webpage. My structure is as follows:

```
C:\ 
¦
¦-- myProj\
    ¦
    ¦index.html
    ¦
    ¦jar\
      ¦
     jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429\
      ¦
      ¦(some jetty folders...)
      ¦(some jetty files...)
      ¦start.jar
```

and inside the folder `C:\myProj\jar\jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429`  I have unzipped `jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429.zip` which I downloaded from [Eclipse Jetty Downloads](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.4.18.v20190429/jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429.zip).

I then `cd C:\myProj` and try to start the server with the following

```
java -jar ./jar/jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429/start.jar
```

However I receive the following msg

```
    C:\myProj>java -jar ./jar/jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429/start.jar
ERROR : Nothing to start, exiting ...

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information
```

What am I doing wrong please? According to this example near the bottom of the page in the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-base-and-home.html) 
it should work

*"The following demonstrates this by allowing default discovery of ${jetty.home} via locating the start.jar, and using the user.dir System Property for ${jetty.base}."*

```
[jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429]$ pwd
/home/user/jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429

[jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429]$ cd /home/user/my-base
[my-base]$ java -jar /home/user/jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429/start.jar

2013-10-16 09:08:47.802:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.18.v20190429
2013-10-16 09:08:47.817:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/home/user/my-base/webapps/] at interval 1
```

Obviously I must be missing something here....

Comment: I had the same issue. Maybe this answer can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35797802/10775356

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on MacOS with Jetty 9.4.x.
Upgrading to Jetty 10.0.0 solved the problem.
It seems specific to Jetty 9.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.

[The documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#quickstart-common-config) states that you need to create a `start.d` directory and specify the Jetty modules to run:

```
> java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --create-startd
INFO : Base directory was modified
> java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy

INFO: server          initialised (transitively) in ${jetty.base}/start.d/server.ini
INFO: http            initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.d/http.ini
INFO: security        initialised (transitively) in ${jetty.base}/start.d/security.ini
INFO: servlet         initialised (transitively) in ${jetty.base}/start.d/servlet.ini
INFO: webapp          initialised (transitively) in ${jetty.base}/start.d/webapp.ini
INFO: deploy          initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.d/deploy.ini
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/webapps
INFO: Base directory was modified

> cp $JETTY_HOME/demo-base/webapps/async-rest.war webapps/ROOT.war
> java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar

2015-06-04 11:10:16.286:INFO::main: Logging initialized @274ms
```

Copying the `start.ini` from the Jetty home to the base dir and modifying it also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following steps really helped:

```bash
JETTY_HOME="<the path to the jetty home folder>"
JETTY_BASE="<the path to the jetty base folder>"
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar jetty.base=$JETTY_BASE jetty.home=$JETTY_HOME
```

As you can see, I've set the `jetty.base` and `jetty.home` properties during the  startup of Jetty.

`JETTY_HOME`: This is the location for the Jetty distribution binaries, default XML IoC configurations, and default module definitions. In my case, it was `/jetty-home-10.0.15`.

`JETTY_BASE`: This is the location for your configurations and customizations to the Jetty distribution. Usually, it's the root directory where you installed Jetty. In my case, it was `/jetty-home-10.0.15/base`.

You can create the `JETTY_BASE` directory using the following commands:

```bash
cd $JETTY_HOME
mkdir base
cd base
java -jar ../start.jar --create-startd
```

PS.

- Since some `MacOS` users may still experience problems, upgrading Jetty from `9.4.*` to `10.0.*` can be really helpful. It helped in my case, at least.
- Also, removing some modules helped me, e.g., the `demo` module in my case.

---

Here is [the official documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/operations-guide/index.html#og-begin-start) on how to start Jetty with different paths.

This article could also be useful - [link](https://xy2401.com/local-docs/java/jetty.9.4.24.v20191120/startup-base-and-home.html).

Answer (score -1):

The `start.jar` in the `${jetty.home}` directory (in your case that directory is `/home/user/jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429/`) is for starting a configured instance of Jetty.

> Note: you can also use the newer [`jetty-home-<ver>.tar.gz` artifact](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.eclipse.jetty%20AND%20a:jetty-home&core=gav) 
>   instead of the older `jetty-distribution` artifact.

What does that mean?

Well, it means ...

- You have a `${jetty.base}` directory somewhere
- The `${jetty.base}` directory doesn't overlap with the `${jetty.home}` directory (and vice-versa)
- The `${jetty.base}` directory has its configuration in `*.ini` files.

  - First it looks for `${jetty.base}/start.ini`
  - Then it looks for `${jetty.base}/start.d/*.ini`
- Each line in the various `*.ini` files are just command line options for `start.jar`

You can see this configuration by using the `--list-config` option.

example:

```
[~]$ cd /home/user/my-base
[my-base]$ java -jar /home/user/jetty-distribution-9.4.18.v20190429/start.jar --list-config
```

Comment: are there any examples on how to do set `jetty.base` please especially in windows. I tried  `SET JETTY_BASE='C:\myProj\jar'` but obviously it doesnt work. All I want to achieve is to serve a dir and then open an html file. Many thanks!

Comment: jetty.base is a directory. it's always the current working directory. you cd into it, and then run the commands. as shown in the answer.    Since this is stackoverflow, with a focus on programming, why not just make a simple embedded-jetty server that does exactly what you want/need, without all of the extra work that jetty-standalone brings into the picture?

Comment: i wanted a portable solution, something that doesnt require the end user to install any programs or other dependencies and also I just do not know java