# Deploying Java application on remote server using Maven

Tags: java, maven, scp

I am writing a Java application using Maven. I have to deploy the application on a remote powerful server to run experiments. The simplest way I figured out to do this was to build a jar-with-dependencies using Maven shading plugin and then copy the uber-jar to the remote server. However the jar is big, 100+ MB, and it takes some time to send it through our network. This is redundant because most of the jar consist of heavy dependencies (Scala, Spark, Jetty) and only a tiny portion of it changes when we change our code.

Can I use Maven to install the dependencies on the remote server and then only send the much smaller jar with no dependencies to the server?

I have SSH connection to the server and I can use the SCP plugin.

Comment: If a server is powerful why not just build it there?

Comment: You could make an uberjar of "everything else", send it once, then add your "changeable" stuff to the class path when you run it on the remote server... see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath

Comment: @YegorChumakov then I need to send the code to the server and it is a redundant step, I don't use it as a development machine, and I don't want to push to get git every time I change the code

Answer (score 0):

You mention Jetty in your question so I am assuming your application server is Jetty. I would try and upload the common library jars to the server and then including them in the jetty class path. This will be a one time task. Maybe this will help: [How do I place jars in jetty/lib on the jetty classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661110/how-do-i-place-jars-in-jetty-lib-on-the-jetty-classpath).

After this you can use maven to built a "thin" war/jar which you can upload and deploy.

Comment: Jetty is mentioned as an example. I also have a case in which I do not use jetty

Comment: The solution still applies for any application server. Upload your third party jars to your server's lib directory.  And use maven to built a "thin" war/jar which you can upload and deploy.